# docker login error on pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am unable to login via Jenkins pipeline on my docker my code as follow.

```
 // Build Docker image
    stage 'Build and Push code'
    withCredentials(
        [[
            $class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
            credentialsId: 'rkstar007',
            passwordVariable: 'DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD',
            usernameVariable: 'DOCKERHUB_USERNAME'
        ]]
    ) {
       sh "docker login -u '${env.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME}' -p '${env.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD}'"
       sh "docker build -t rkstar007/mesosphere:${gitCommit()} ."
       sh "docker push rkstar007/mesosphere:${gitCommit()}"
     }
```

Comment: what's the actual error? are you also logging out of docker in the same pipe?

Comment: Can you put the error log?